# Registering application in Azure portal using 'POST /applications' Graph endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying come up with a bash script to register an application in Azure AD using the `/beta/applications` endpoint from Microsoft Graph.

To call `/applications`, I would need to get an access token.

Is it possible to get an access token for Microsoft Graph using just email address/password (Without a `client-id`)? I am looking for something like "Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant Flow" mentioned in OAUTH2 spec.

Any other alternative I can look into. I want to write a simple script that would manage application registration and any updates to the application in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several means of running a script against the Microsoft Graph API without a user present:

[AD supports the *resource owner credential grant*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) that you described in your question. This flow doesn't support some new auth features like multifactor auth and you'll have to be very careful about securely storing your credentials.

The other option is to use V2 [*auth client credential flow*](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). In this case, the tenant admin consents to the application on behalf of the tenant. Afterwards, the application can run without a user present. One benefit of this flow as opposed to the V1 *resource owner credential grant* is that you pass a client credential which can be revoked and re-generated if needed (rather than dealing with raw user credentials).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was able to register the applications via 'POST /applications' api after getting token using the first link you gave. In my case i do not have a client_id. I am just now registering my application. So i used the client_id "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2" which seems to be used by PowerShell. Is there a way to get token using only username/password without client_id.

Comment: I think for the grant, you will need a client_id to uniquely identify what application you're getting the token for.